# Jquery - remove item identified by ID passed in through function

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an HTML list, in its simplest form:

```
<div class="row" id="row-31">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <button onClick="removeRow('row-31')">
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my scripts:

```
function removeRow(row){
    console.log(row);
    ('#' + row).remove();
}
```

Inside the JS, I've also tried `(row).remove();`, etc. I log the correct row ID to remove, but i can't get it to disappear.

Before moving it to a function, I could delete the row using `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` (since the button is in an enclosing div - bootstrap row and col), but the problem was, since the user can create new rows, the script wasn't binding to the dynamically created button, so I moved it into a function. Now the script fires, but it can't remove an item by it's ID.

Can anyone give me a pointer, please?

I can either get this to work 90% of the way or 10% of the way, but not 100% :)

(if it matters, the row ID is being generated by PHP, but I don't think that's the issue)

Comment: `$('#' + row).remove();` See the `$`?

Comment: And it's very strange - why use `onclick` if you can bind handler with jQuery?

Comment: you wont have to post this long question if you once tried to check the console error and tried to understand,a user like you with 500+ repo should have cought that mann

Comment: learn how to open your browser's Developer Tools (F12) and check the console...then you'd have seen the error message caused by your code. The tools are there to help you, start using them and you will solve simple problems like this very easily.

Comment: @u_mulder - I tried adding the `$` and still doesn't work. I'm logging before and after that event, the script continues right through it without removing the item.

Comment: `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)` right before you try to remove and verify that you see a version number log to your console.

Comment: So instead of finding out __why__ your binding doesn't work on dynamically added elements you decided to add a function. Okay. The solution - bind with `on()` function.

Comment: @ADyson - there was a typo in the code I entered into SO, not in my page. No errors are being shown in my console.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski, I have tried this in a snippet and it works fine. You must have another issue somewhere.

Comment: @Taplar - its version 3.3.1

Comment: @LucasKrupinski if thats a typo in SO, please fix your post :)

Comment: So the method is happening, and jQuery is included.  Hmm.  `console.log($('#'+ row).length)` and verify that you get 1

Comment: If you load the page the first time (PHP), the row was in the dom in the first place, and easy to remove with JQuery. But if you pressed add row and had a new row dynamically added with its own delete button, that delete button wouldn't work. So i moved to using a function, and pass in the row ID that way. But that doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: You're doing an inline binding, so as long as the method is a global method the dynamic creation should not matter.

Comment: @Taplar - the length returns as 33, which is the correct length! :) Again, I tried to consolidate this down to a minimal version of the issue!

Comment: Wait, what?  No.  Length off of an id lookup should only ever return 1 or 0

Comment: @taplar - I'm sorry. The length of the ID is 33, but you're correct - it returns 0, not 1.

Comment: Then if it returns 0, that means you are not finding the element at that point in time.  Meaning either the selector is inaccurate, or the element that will have that id does not exist yet.

Comment: I posted a comment below - I think my issue was with my ID's themselves. They were like `1.0.3f1a32r4a15` - when I hardcoded an ID into the JS, PHP storm flagged it as an error, so I added a alpha prefix and changed the separator to a `-` and then it began working. I think (?) JQ was evaluating the ID as if it was a number even though there were letters in it. I'm not sure, but it got resolved!

Answer (score 2):

Close your `button` and add the `$` before you remove.

```js
function removeRow(row){
    console.log(row);
    $('#' + row).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="row-31">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button onClick="removeRow('row-31')">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a better solution.  For this one, I would suggest using something other than `body`, as it will fire every click on the `body`. If you have a higher up element that isn't dynamically added, use that instead.

```js
$( "body").on( "click", ".remove", function() {
  console.log($(this).data('value'));
  $('#' + $(this).data('value')).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="row-31">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button class="remove" data-value="row-31">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although a solid answer.... his new revaluation of "the length returns as 33" for a single ID element....... me thinks he has bigger fish eating up his worms. =D

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I also assumed that, but wanted to make sure he knew his assumptions as to what wasn't working was actually working.  It's home time now, so I'll remove this later if it doesn't apply.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer, but I think it's solved.

Originally, the full ID's were:

    $model->key = '1.0.' . bin2hex(random_bytes(12));

I changed it to give it a letter prefix and dash separators;

    $model->key = 'A1-0-' . bin2hex(random_bytes(12));

I thought of this because when I hardcoded a value into my script, PHPStorm highlighted as if it was in error.